# Flask и Openvpn

Tags: python, linux, сеть, flask, маршрутизация

Честно гуглил весь день, но то ли я дурак, то ли лыжи не едут...

На машине с Дебиан успешно работало приложение на Python3 с Flask: из телеграмм приходили вебхуки, и все было хорошо, не считая что обратно в телеграмм сообщения уходили через раз, всему бедой бесплатные прокси... Не мудрствовая лукаво, купил vpn, установил openvpn и, о чудо, сообщения в телегу понеслись рекой. Но теперь не приходят сообщения от телеги!!!

Так как в роутере переадресацию не менял, догадываюсь, что проблема в таблице маршрутизации в Дебиан, но вот как решать эту проблему, ума не приложу.

Вот выдача netstat -rn

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.180.0.1      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.180.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.180.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.180.0.1      128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
192.40.220.117  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

Flask висел на 0.0.0.0:5000, адрес машины 192.168.1.110
Запускал Flask на 192.168.1.110:5000 - эффекта 0.

Надеюсь на помощь уважаемого сообщества.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/117620/ почитай тут. тебе нужна вторая таблица маршрутизации.

Comment: Предположу что в вашем случае вы пустили весь трафик сервера через туннель. Для работы хука нужно чтобы сервер телеграмм смог исполнить код, который вероятно у вас на веб сервере доступном из интернет. Но изменив маршрут в туннель вы сделали недоступным этот сервер для серверов телеграмм. Простая проверка - отключаем/включаем туннель стучимся на сервер - telnet server.address.com port_number. Сверяем результаты. И нужно понимать ваш внутренний сокет 192.168.1.110:5000 пробрасывается наружу через NAT или у этого сервера есть публичный адрес.